# SDL OpenGL C++ problem

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to make a simple game of pong using SDL and OpenGL in C++ and I'm having trouble displaying any sort of OpenGL image onto the screen and was wondering if anybody could help:

Initialization:

```
void init_everything()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    SDL_SetVideoMode( width_of_screen, height_of_screen, bpp_of_screen, SDL_OPENGL );

    glClearColor( 0, 0, 0, 0 );

    // Sets the projection
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, width_of_screen, height_of_screen, 0, 1, -1 );

    // initalises the modelview matrix
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Pong - By Michael Clover", NULL );
}
```

After this I call the class function:

```
void paddle::show()
{
    //Move to offset
    glTranslatef( x, y, 0 );

    //Start quad
    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        //Set color to white
        glColor4f( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

        //Draw square
        glVertex3f( 0,            0,             0 );
        glVertex3f( paddle_width, 0,             0 );
        glVertex3f( paddle_width, paddle_height, 0 );
        glVertex3f( 0,            paddle_height, 0 );

    //End quad
    glEnd();

    //Reset
    glLoadIdentity();

}
```

I then put this in my main function:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    bool quit = false;

    init_everything();

    paddle playerpaddle;

    while (quit == false )
    {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            playerpaddle.handle_input();

            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        playerpaddle.move();
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        playerpaddle.show();
        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    }

    clean_up();
    return 0;
}
```

All I get is a constant black background screen that I set within a 640 by 480px SDL screen.

Sorry for the huge amount of text and I would be extremely grateful for any insight on what the problem could be here, I'm guessing I'm making a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: Make a call to glGetError() after you make openGL calls.  Make sure you have no errors first!

Comment: Steve O'Connor: I tried what you suggested, nothing appeared to have changed when I rebuilt the program, thanks for the suggestion though. Just to clear up, I never mentioned when I asked the question that this is going to be 2D

Comment: It won't change anything that you can see, you're gonna need to read the return value of the function. Use that to determine where you have errors.

Comment: I'm getting no errors after inserting glGetError(); after every function :/

Comment: So you stored the return value into a gLenum and checked that value (by breaking through, for example), correct?

Comment: I also just realized your first comment was to Steve O'connor, not me, rofl...In the future, please put comments to users on their answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I am new to stackoverflow. No, I didn't store them into a glenum, I have not encountered any problems whilst I have been learning OpenGL so far, I haven't been learning it for long though. I have no idea how to go about storing their value into a glenum.

Comment: Haha, no big deal, it happens.  As for gLenum, it's fairly straighforward.  Declare a variable of type GLEnum and set that equal to the glGetError() function.  Ex: GLEnum check = glGetError().  Then use break points to see what the value of check is after glGetError() is called.  The case of no errors will return 0.

Comment: Thanks, tried this after every opengl statement was called and I got 0 returned from everything.

Answer (score 2):

I think glOrtho might be set up wrong. The last 2 parameters are near and far clipping planes. Your near plane should be less than zero if you don't want to clip your paddle. And your far plane should be greater than zero. So try this:

```
glOrtho( 0, width_of_screen, height_of_screen, 0, -1, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after replacing the code with your suggestion nothing changed :/

Comment: Out of curiosity because I've never used it, what does glOrtho do exactly?

Comment: glOrtho creates a projection that is parallel, which means objects further away from the viewer have the same size. A normal 3d projection makes objects look smaller the further they are away, thereby creating the sense of perspective that your eye gives you.

Answer (score 0):

Just 2 things to check now that you've ruled out errors:

1. Try removing the glTranslatef call.  It may be too far off for you to see the scene.
2. Are you creating your vertices in a clockwise order?  I can't tell by the variables you used, but if paddle_height is > 0 or paddle_width < 0, it's not going to be clockwise (which it needs to be).

Comment: const int paddle_width = 10; const int paddle_height = 40; - I think I might be going insane, 0, 0 coordinates is the top right corner of the screen right?

Comment: No, (0,0) in openGL is dead center. top left is (-1,1), bottom right is (1,-1). So not only are you not drawing clock wise, but you're dimensions are HUGE!

Comment: OK, I've really confused myself now, I took out the call to glTranslatef and the paddle appeared in the top left corner of the screen

Comment: With coordinates (0,0)?  I wonder if glOrtho() has something to do with that.  Looks like I've learned something new haha!  Well, good, you have something now!  Experiment a bit, see if you can move it to right center.  As for translatef(), that function shifts the scene around, so you were most likely drawing off screen earlier.

Comment: my glOrtho is set to 640 by 480 width and height dimensions, so is the SDL screen. I'm still at a loss as to what I can do now because I was relying on using gltranslatef to move the object around the screen

Comment: Don't move objects with glTranslatef(), just move their actual drawing coordinates!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your projection instead (if you want 0,0,0 at your center).

```
double range = 4.0; // Set this to whatever you want for the range of the display.
double ratio = double(displayWidth) / double(displayHeight);
glOrtho(-range* ratio, range* ratio, -range, range, -1.0, 1.0);
```

Temporarily try to render a square from -1.0,-1.0 to 1.0,1.0 to see if your display is working.